# Is there any ways to render JSON errors instead of Cloudflare captcha (challenge page)?

Tags: html, json, cloudflare, ddos

Our application using both web and api, but when the users move to some locations as Sri Lanka, Russia,... the mobile application can not access our apis because Cloudflare renders html challenge page. Is the any configs on Cloudflare to render JSON or challenge page (html) base on request (html or JSON)?